# Раняя регистрация доменов

Tags: домен

Недавно рылся по "топовых" доменных именах, и вот наткнулся на имя "pay.me", чекнув whois я узнал что дата реестрации 29 апреля 2008 года:

```
Registered On:2008-04-29
```

https://www.whois.com/whois/pay.me - ссылка. Но так же я узнал из Википедии что

> 6 мая 2008 года стал доступен для регистрации доменов

Т.е. за неделю до доступа к реестрации его уже забрали, почему так?

P.S. Не понимаю какие метки тут подходят кроме "домен"

Comment: Потому что хорошие домены резервируются до открытия массовой регистрации. Это известный факт

Comment: @РашенБеар можно ссылку на статью?

Comment: Не искал таких статей. Просто следил за открытием новой доменной зоны. Там несколько этапов регистрации есть.